# How to get value string with regexp in bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

Hi i have string in BigQuery column like this

```
cancellation_amount: 602000
after_cancellation_transaction_amount: 144500
refund_time: '2022-07-31T06:05:55.215203Z'
cancellation_amount: 144500
after_cancellation_transaction_amount: 0
refund_time: '2022-08-01T01:22:45.94919Z'
```

i already using this logic to get cancellation_amount

```
regexp_extract(file,r'.*cancellation_amount:\s*([^\n\r]*)')
```

but the output only amount 602000, i need the output 602000 and 144500 become different column

Appreciate for helping

Answer (score 0):

If your lines in the input (which will eventually become columns) are fixed you can use multiple `regexp_extract`s to get all the values.

```
SELECT
    regexp_extract(file,r'cancellation_amount:\s*([^\n\r]*)') as cancellation_amount
    regexp_extract(file,r'. after_cancellation_transaction_amount:\s*([^\n\r]*)') as after_cancellation_transaction_amount
FROM table_name
```

One issue I found with your regex expression is that `.*cancellation_amount` won't match `after_cancellation_transaction_amount`.

There is also a function called `regexp_extract_all` which returns all the matches as an array which you can later explode into columns, but if you have finite values separating them out in different columns would be a easier.